# Is this an infinite loop? What am I doing wrong? (Java method)

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm supposed to write a "bisquare" method that returns the number of bisquares in a range of numbers. I thought I'd figured it out, but when I run this code, nothing displays and my laptop begins to whir like crazy. The system never says it finished.

Here is my code. What am I doing wrong? (I am also looking for a solution to the problem if I am not setting it up correctly.)

```
   // An integer that is the sum of the squares of two other integers is called bisquare
   // 5 is bisquare because it is 1*1 + 2*2
   // 4 is bisquare because it is 0*0 + 2*2  (we can use 0 as one of our numbers)
   // 8 is bisquare because it is 2*2 + 2*2  (we can use the same two numbers)
   // 3 is not bisquare, 6 is not bisquare
   //  
   // Given two int parameters, low and high, return the number of bisquares that
   // fall between low and high (inclusive)
   // 
   // EXAMPLES:
   // low = 1, high = 6
   // return 4
   // 1, 2, 4, and 5 are bisquare.  3 and 6 are not
   //
   // low = 7, high = 7
   // return 0
   // 7 is not bisquare.  that is the entire range we are checking. 

   public static int bisquare(int low, int high)
   {      
      int count = 0;
      boolean isBisquare = false;
      for (int checkNum = low; checkNum < high; checkNum++) {
         while (!isBisquare) {
            for (int i = 0; i < high; i++) {
               for (int j = 0; j < high; j++) {
                  if ((i*i) + (j*j) == low) {
                     count++;
                     isBisquare = true;
                  }
               }
            }   
         }
      }
      return count;
   }
```

Comment: What are your inputs?

Comment: What is `checkNum` supposed to do?

Comment: what is the use of `checkNum `

Comment: if low is not the sum of two square numbers then it won't ever end... For example, low = 7.

Comment: I see no reason to use the while loop. There aren't any parameters that might change for the next iteration. No while-loop, no infinite loop.

Comment: See one of Fermat's lesser known theorems: "A number N is expressible as a sum of 2 squares if and only if in the prime factorization of N, every prime of the form (4k+3) occurs an even number of times". You could implement your solution using that. It will probably be faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,
If none of the `(i*i) + (j*j) == low` evaluates to true the while will loop infinitely.

Comment: Thank you, you're right! What can I do as an alternative solution?

Comment: Make sure you increment low so that you move to the next number and change the condition to put some limit on how much low can increase.

Comment: Alternatively only increase checkNum when you find your number and iterate with low.

Comment: Sorin, I wish I could accept your comment as an answer, this helped a lot! I ended up incrementing checkNum and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

The first thing is the loop

```
while (!isBisquare) {
    // some code
}
```

The code in this loop is executed in precisely the same way each time, so if no bisquare is found the first time the code in the loop executes, biSquare is not set to true and will not be set to true in further iterations, leading to an infinite loop.

The second problem is this line:

```
if ((i*i) + (j*j) == low) {
```

I think this should be

```
if ((i*i) + (j*j) == checkNum) {
```

otherwise you always check for the lowest number in the range whether it is a bisquare.

Combine these two errors and you get an infinite loop whenever the argument low is not a bisquare, regardless of the value of high.

**EDIT:** Initially I didn't notice what you meant to do with the while loop. After reading some of the discussion I do realize it was to prevent counting one number multiple times. I suggest using @Clashsoft's second solution. This makes the code much more readable and reusable.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the `checkNum` variable correctly. It should be used in the inner two for loops. Also, the `while` loop is unnecessary and creates an infinite loop for numbers that are not bisquares.

```
public static int bisquare(int low, int high)
{      
    int count = 0;
    for (int checkNum = low; checkNum < high; checkNum++)
    {
        outerloop:
        for (int i = 0; i < checkNum; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < checkNum; j++)
            {
                if (i * i + j * j == checkNum)
                {
                    count++;
                    break outerloop;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

For reasons of clarity, you should probably also consider creating a `isBisquare(int)` method like this:

```
public static boolean isBisquare(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (i * i + j * j == n)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The `bisquare` method (which should have a better name, say `countBisquares`) now looks like this:

```
public static int countBisquares(int low, int high)
{      
    int count = 0;
    for (int checkNum = low; checkNum < high; checkNum++)
    {
        if (isBisquare(checkNum))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I implement this, then if low = 1 and high = 10 it will return 10, which is incorrect. This is because the nested for loops count some numbers twice. Example: 4 yields (0*0)+(2*2) and (2*2)+(0*0). This is why I felt the need to use the while loop, to break out of this.

Comment: The separate method is necessary, a number may be biSquared in more than one way. But only one way should be counted. For the first example to work, you should break after ```count++```, using a label. I'll make a suggested edit.

Comment: I'm not allowed a separate method in this solution, unfortunately, although I appreciate the effort.

Comment: I accepted the edit. Using `break` (or `continue`ing the outermost loop) is required in this scenario; it cannot be solved with a `while` loop in a sane way.

Comment: Not quite sure if this will work... Wouldn't `0,1`, and `1,0` both return true?

Comment: Yes, because there are often multiple solutions. But it would only be counted once when using the extra method or `continue/break`.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic was not correct. Below is the correct one:

```
    public static int bisquare(int low, int high) {
        int count = 0;
        boolean isBisquare = false;
        for (int checkNum = low; checkNum < high; checkNum++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < checkNum && !isBisquare; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < checkNum && !isBisquare; j++) {
                    if (((i * i) + (j * j)) == checkNum) {
                        count++;
                        isBisquare = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            isBisquare = false;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: I would put `boolean isBisquare = false;` in the first for loop: this is the scope in which it is used and makes it more clear that its value should not be carried over to the next iteration. This is the good solution - I (and the other answerers apparently, had not noticed that was what he meant to do with `isBisquare`. You should explain his mistake instead of just giving the code though.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried some of the above solutions and I believe I have found an error in all of the above solutions. In the *all* of the for loops, checkNum should be less than or *equal to* high, and i or j should be less than or *equal to* checkNum.

Making these changes will give the answer 7 when given a high of 10 and a low of 1. without these changes, the answer is 5 given the same inputs.

It don't think it will ever count actual high and low values unless this change is made.